# Multiple background image CSS repeat

Tags: html, css

I have a div and i want to give it 3 backgrounds

```
background:url(../images/left-bg.png) no-repeat left,url(../images/right-bg.png) no-repeat right,url(../images/center-bg.png) repeat-x;
```

the background image of left and right is transparent but because my center background image is repeat-x the center background goes under left and right backgrounds, is there any way to stop this event?

thank you

Comment: question not clear. can u please provide jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the larger context — CSS3 has the [`background-origin` property](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-origin) that decides whether your background is only painted behind the content-box, or the padding-box, or the border-box.

If your left and right images are borderish in nature, having the repeated image on `content-box` and the left/right images on `padding-box`/`border-box` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using like this example

```
body{
    background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/200/100/) ,url(http://lorempixel.com/202/100/) ,url(http://lorempixel.com/203/100/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x;
    background-position: left, right;
}
```

here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/2ju4g2p9/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
It is possible to have 3 backgrounds using CSS3 , it is a new functionality added to CSS .
```

```css
#multiple_bg{
    background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flwr.gif), url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/paper.gif);
    background-position: right bottom, left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="multiple_bg">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
```

```
SUPPORT - [I.E :9.0],[CHROME:4.0],[MOZILLA 3.6 ],[SAFARI 3.1],[Opera 11.5]
```